# Using Signalr for certain records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am using **asp.net MVC** and **sql server**.

I have certain testers which have some detailed records. For each tester there is at least 100 detailed records. When a certain column gets updated in this detailed table, I need to send the updated data to this particular record(testerID). 
For example:

- testerid=1 and detailed table has 100 records with testerID=1, when testertable gets updated then update the view of this tester record. If a user has another tester open in his webpage, changes to any other tester's detailed record should not refresh this view.

currently I use polling timer.js and talk to db to check if the database has changed and update the view. I want to use **signalR**, Is **SignalR** the right technlogy for this purpose?

Comment: First of all, you should simplify the question as much as possible without giving us implementation details. It makes it really harder to understand what you ask since you included unnecessary details in your question.

Comment: Secondly, what is the way that you identify your users? Do you have a user id? Moreover, do you have a way to update all instances of the same test?

Comment: Regarding the user id, I think it is not directly related to userid. The reason is I want all the users who have open a particular tester in thier webpage must get the updated detailed information. For ex if users a,b,c have open a particular tester T1, then if the detailed table(T1 related record Detail table) is modified, then broadcast the change to the clients/machines/users who have T1 tester open in their webpage. If some machine/user has T2 tester open and if none of the records related to this is modified, then they should not get notified since T2 wasn't modified

Comment: I am actually sorry, I do not know what a tester is. And this might be the case with other people. That is what I was trying to say. Simplify your question (if possible, of course) to the point where you do not need additional information. Thanks!

Comment: There are two tables master and detail. Master has 1,2,3 as master ID and detail has records related to master ID's 1,2 and 3. I modify some data in the detail table with masterID 1, I want this message to be broadcast to only master 1(web page if anyone has it open) and not all masters. Can we target signalr updates based on the master record ID?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code where you actually do the update, then yes, it is possible. (For example if you do it using Entity Framework and you have access to the code).

When you update the values regarding a specific `MasterId`, simply update all clients connected to the `MasterId` instance.

For this, you will also need to keep a mapping between users and the page they have opened (between SignalR `ConnectionId` and the `MasterId`.

Assuming you have  `List<string> connectionIds` containing all `ConnectionId` of the clients connected to `MasterId`, then you can them the notification in the following way:

```
foreach(var connectionId in connectionIds)
{
Clients.Client(connectionId).doSomething(param list);
}
```

The main things you should understand:

- make sure you have access to the code that actually does the update
- make sure to keep a mapping between the connection id of the client and the clients using a specific Master Id.

Hope this helps!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Radu for your time! Basically there are a couple of windows services that updates the detailed table. I am using EF. I am not sure I understand your solution. Is it possible to give an example with master-detailed table scenario please? When masterid 1 related data is updated, only masterid1 should get te updated data not any other masterid. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: My problem is very similar to this thread. But the solution proposed there suggestd to use userid. I will not have any userid. http://forums.asp.net/t/2028264.aspx?Send+data+to+specific+client+from+server